# replace for loop to parallel process in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using for loop in my script to call a function for each element of size_DF(data frame) but it is taking lot of time. I tried by removing the for loop by map but i am not getting any output.
size_DF is list of around 300 element which i am fetching from a table.

Using For:

```
import call_functions

newObject = call_functions.call_functions_class()
size_RDD = sc.parallelize(size_DF) 

if len(size_DF) == 0:
    print "No record present in the truncated list"
else:

    for row in size_DF:
        length = row[0]
        print "length: ", length
        insertDF = newObject.full_item(sc, dataBase, length, end_date)
```

Using Map

```
if len(size_DF) == 0:
    print "No record present in the list"
else:
    size_RDD.mapPartition(lambda l: newObject.full_item(sc, dataBase, len(l[0]), end_date))
```

**newObject.full_item(sc, dataBase, len(l[0]), end_date)** 
In full_item() -- I am doing some select ope and joining 2 tables and inserting the data into a table.

Please help me and let me know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: what does `full_item(sc, dataBase, length, end_date)` do exactly? You need to update the question with as much information as you can.

Comment: You are not saving the output of `size_RDD.mapPartition`

Comment: Do you need the result for whatever `newObject.full_item` does assigned to insertDF? Or do you just need to run `newObject.full_item` routine for each partition and not concerned about the result?

Comment: as updated in question 
**newObject.full_item(sc, dataBase, len(l[0]), end_date)** 
In full_item() -- we are doing some select ope and we are joining 2 tables and inserting the data into a table.

Comment: @Oluwafemi Sule No I don't need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pyspark.rdd.RDD.mapPartition` method is lazily evaluated.
Usually to force an evaluation, you can a method that returns a value on the lazy RDD instance that is returned.

There are higher-level functions that take care of forcing an evaluation of the `RDD` values. **e.g.** [`pyspark.rdd.RDD.foreach`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.0/python/pyspark/rdd.py#L786)

Since you don't really care about the results of the operation you can use `pyspark.rdd.RDD.foreach` instead of `pyspark.rdd.RDD.mapPartition`.

```
def first_of(it):
    for first in it:
        return first
    return []

def insert_first(it):
    first = first_of(it)
    item_count = len(first)
    newObject.full_item(sc, dataBase, item_count, end_date)


if len(size_DF) == 0:
    print('No record present in the truncated list')
else:
    size_DF.forEach(insert_first)
```

Comment: But using for() and forEach() it is taking lots of time. I just want to use parallel processing concept of spark rdd and thats why i am using .mapPartitions().

Comment: `forEach` or `foreachPartition` also uses the workers.  `forEach` is equivalent to `mapPartitions(func).count()`

Comment: what is this is function for def first_of(it):  ??

Comment: The `first_of` function returns the first item in an iterable without consuming the entire iterate in memory.

Comment: .. But i want to pass the length of each element of size_DF to the function like this      
 
for row in size_DF:
        length = row[0]
        print "length: ", length
        insertDF = newObject.full_item(sc, dataBase, length, end_date)

Comment: That's what is passed. `first_of` returns `it[0]` safely in case it is a generator. if `it` is a row in `size_DF`, are you looking to insert the `len(it[0])` or `len(it)`?