# Parallelize an operation applied to a list (PySpark)

Tags: python, pyspark, parallel-processing

At one point in my program, a function receives a list and repeats an operation using each of its items.

For the sake of this example, suppose my program starts off with a list `l` and counts the rows of some generic pyspark dataframe `df` that meet a condition.

```py
l = [2, 4, 5]
res = []

for x in l:
    val = df.where((col('id') == x) | (col('id2') == x)).count()
    res.append(val)
```

Is it possible to have multiple workers calculate `val` simultaneously? That is, could each worker calculate its own `val` and append it to `l` individually?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49023893/replace-for-loop-to-parallel-process-in-pyspark) suggests using `foreach`, but since I'm iterating over a list (not an RDD or dataframe), I cannot use that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try `array_intersect` to find the matching rows.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

l = [2, 4, 5]
# Convert to Col type
l = [F.lit(x) for x in l]

df = (df.withColumn('intersect', F.array_intersect(F.array('id', 'id2'), F.array(l)))
      .select('id', F.explode('intersect').alias('intersect'))
      .groupby('intersect')
      .count())
```

Comment: Thank you @Emma! The case in question was using a dataframe representing the edges of a graph, where `x` can appear in the source or destination columns (so grouping cannot be directly applied). However, I used a case-when to circumvent this and ended up using your solution.

Answer (score 1):

you could do away with loops and use spark functions to count occurrences.

here's an example

```py
# mock input data
data_sdf.show()

# +---+---+
# | id|id2|
# +---+---+
# |  2|  4|
# |  4|  1|
# |  3|  5|
# |  4|  5|
# |  1|  8|
# +---+---+

# create array of all ids, and remove ids that are not in that row
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('id_ls', func.array(*[func.lit(k) for k in ls])). \
    withColumn('id_per_row', func.expr('filter(id_ls, x -> (id = x) or (id2 = x))')). \
    filter(func.size('id_per_row') != 0). \
    select('*', func.explode('id_per_row').alias('ids')). \
    groupBy('ids'). \
    count(). \
    show()

# +---+-----+
# |ids|count|
# +---+-----+
# |4  |3    |
# |2  |1    |
# |5  |2    |
# +---+-----+
```

---

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('id_ls', func.array(*[func.lit(k) for k in ls])). \
    withColumn('id_per_row', func.expr('filter(id_ls, x -> (id = x) or (id2 = x))')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+---+---------+----------+
# |id |id2|id_ls    |id_per_row|
# +---+---+---------+----------+
# |2  |4  |[2, 4, 5]|[2, 4]    |
# |4  |1  |[2, 4, 5]|[4]       |
# |3  |5  |[2, 4, 5]|[5]       |
# |4  |5  |[2, 4, 5]|[4, 5]    |
# |1  |8  |[2, 4, 5]|[]        |
# +---+---+---------+----------+
```